# DBPedia SPARQL working for one movie but not another

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am a SPARQL/DBPedia noob and am trying to use it for a pet project.

I have the following query to find all the people and their role (starring, director, editing, etc.) for a particular movie --

```
PREFIX dbO: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbR: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?p,?o
WHERE {
    dbR:Personal_Shopper ?p ?o.
    ?o rdf:type dbO:Person 
}
```

It returns the expected, so all clear.

However if I replace `Personal_Shopper` with the movie Dunkirk (`Dunkirk_(2017_film)`)

```
PREFIX dbO: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbR: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?p,?o
WHERE {
    dbR:Dunkirk_(2017_film) ?p ?o.
    ?o rdf:type dbO:Person 
}
```

I get an error

`Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 17: syntax error at '2017' before '_film' SPARQL query: define sql:big-data-const 0 #output-format:application/sparql-results+json define input:default-graph-uri PREFIX owl: PREFIX xsd: PREFIX rdfs: PREFIX rdf: PREFIX foaf: PREFIX dc: PREFIX : PREFIX dbpedia2: PREFIX dbpedia: PREFIX skos: PREFIX dbO: PREFIX dbR: SELECT ?p,?o WHERE { dbR:Dunkirk_(2017_film) ?p ?o. ?o rdf:type dbO:Person }`

This is the page for Dunkirk:

http://dbpedia.org/page/Dunkirk_(2017_film)

I thought the name of the resource is the same as that in the Wiki page URL.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkirk_(2017_film)

Can someone point out my mistake?I am running the queries here:

http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

Comment: Try `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dunkirk_(2017_film)>` instead. BTW, [LinkedMDB](http://www.linkedmdb.org/) exists.

Comment: Thanks...it works..Do you know why the prefix works for the other movies but not for this?

Comment: Because some characters are not allowed in prefixed URIs. Here the `(` and `)` characters are not allowed

Comment: @StanislavKralin the LinkedMDB data is quite old (2014 was the last I guess), nobody is updating it as far as I know.

Comment: @Solo Why do you use lower camel-case style for the prefix names?

Comment: @Solo One more comment, you should be aware of the fact that the DBpedia data at dbpedia.org is based on dumps, thus, the data is not in sync with Wikipedia. That's why there is a [DBpedia live endpoint](http://live.dbpedia.org/)

Comment: Escaping the () should work in SPARQL.  `:Dunkirk_\(2017_film\)`. From the deleted answer, it seems it does not work in this installation.

Comment: What is "SparkQL"?  I think you mean SPARQL throughout, but as I'm not certain, I'm not editing to correct that...

Comment: Also worth noting -- errors are presented rather more clearly on the SPARQL endpoint than in the SNORQL interface.  See [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?qtxt=PREFIX+dbO%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbR%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fp%2C%3Fo%0D%0AWHERE+{%0D%0A++++dbR%3ADunkirk_%282017_film%29+%3Fp+%3Fo.%0D%0A++++%3Fo+rdf%3Atype+dbO%3APerson+%0D%0A}).

Comment: Also also — @AndyS is correct that `\(` and `\)` should work here. This is being tracked internally (I work for OpenLink Software; we make Virtuoso) as bug #17428. You can log an [issue on github](http://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/) or [create a Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp) to get notification when this has been addressed and/or to raise its priority.